# OpenX API list linked zone of a campaign

Tags: php, openx

Is there possible to list linked zone of a campaign via OpenX API ?

I found the methods to link and unlink zone in a campaign (linkCampaign, unlinkCampaign) but I can't listed them

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no method to list zones associated with a campaign.

However you have a method to list zones associated with a publisher: getZoneListByPublisherId

Comment: Thank mfernandes, i'll try it and feedback ASAP

Comment: I'm still need another solution. In current i use a log table to store `zone_id` and `campaign_id` then i unlink zone base on it. But it's still have disadvantages because i cannt handle if someone link/unlink the zone direct from openX not from my system. Another problem if i call api to unlink the same id twice or more the system will throw the exception and i got error message. Then i think it's should be more easier if there are some way to get zone list in a campaign